# Warm-up solution Best Practices to improve performance?

Tags: 2010, performance, object-cache, warm-up

Are there best practices or recommendations in using warm up solutions/scripts?

How does one schedule warm up solutions to run periodically? Any information regarding this will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SPWakeup WSS3.0/2007 - http://spwakeup.codeplex.com/

SharePoint 2010/2013 - https://spbestwarmup.codeplex.com/

SharePoint 2013 - http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=404

I've always used it every morning, right after resetting IIS. Just schedule a task scheduler to reset IIS, and then another task scheduler to run this script 2 minutes after.

Comment: Very useful, even on your development environment!

Answer (score 1):

There is many scripts available, some using with PowerShell, some with VB script and some using with the API. Its depend on you which one is best suitable for you.
Another point to think before using any script, do you want to wake up only root level site or all sites in the web applications?
Because now a days many PowerShell scrip basically go through all the sites collections.

One thing, App Pool for web application recycled once in 24 hours( usually around AM hours), you need to schedule it in the morning hours.
here are two blogs i am referencing you, which will give comparison about the Best available scripts.

http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.com/2010/10/sharepoint-2010-warm-up-script.html

http://spwarmup4admin.codeplex.com/